# Why my Model JSON/list attribute in Django sometimes misses data?

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, jsonfield

I'm building a Django project that has to do with generating math/science problems for teachers and students.
The project works fine for some time but when I run it on the browser (with the views all set up) it sometimes get errors that I cant explain how they happen:

Example:

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    attribute = JSONField() #it is a list of strings ['a', 'b', 'c']
    
    def myfunc(self):
        do something with (self.attribute)
```

The problem is that every now and then, the program runs into an error mainly because when myfunc calls `self.attribute` it returns the list with items missing! Like, in this case, it may return `['a', 'b']`.

I've never seen any error like this, so I don't know what to do. I obviously double checked if the attribute is really with all the variables I expeceted it to be, that's not the problem. Has anyone seen anything like this that could help?

I strongly believe that it has something to do with how Django gets the data in the JSONField and parses it to a list or dict to work with that, but again I don't know what to do about it.

Comment: We can't possibly help without seeing the code...

Comment: There's no between code in the problem I'm relating. The problem is plainly this: the variable is a list with some items. When I call a function that uses that list, it sometimes brings a list with an item missing. The rest of the code doesn't have to do with this, but it depends on it.

Comment: Then the only answer we can give is "you have wrong code somewhere".